# Knowing When Video is Done Playing in VLC

Tags: java, eclipse, video, vlc

My Java Application is opening videos in VLC and I want to play a second video after the first video is over. Right now I am setting a timer that is equal to the length of each video. At the end of the timer, I play the next video. Is there a way I can detect the end of the video? Some other sources have mentioned adding a listener. Here is my code:

```
String[] s = new String[] {"C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe", "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\" + filename + ".mp4"};

  try {

    Process process = runtime.exec(s);

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.schedule( new TimerTask(){
       public void run() {           
           Start();          
       }
     }, delay);
```

I call Start() recursively above, but I change the filename and the duration.

Comment: Why not just specify all the vidoes in a single command line, from the [cli docs](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help), *"You can specify multiple streams on the commandline.  They will be enqueued in the playlist.  The first item specified will be played first."*

Comment: ps- Use `ProcessBuilder`, seriously, it handles spaces in parameters betters, has redirection support for output streams, allows you specify the working directory and lots more...

Answer (score 1):

VLC has a command-line option you can append after the video you want, it's `--play-and-exit`. It will cause VLC to exit after the video is done, allowing your program to continue. I also found it's possible specify multiple videos for a playlist and it will play all the videos in the playlist before exiting, if that may be useful to you.